# Dynamics CRM Marketing Form - Send CRM data to CMS hosted form

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365

In Dynamics 365/CRM Marketing, I have a Marketing Form that's hosted (injected) into a CMS.

I'm trying to validate the email addresses users enter against a list of invalid email domains pulled from Dynamics 365/CRM.

Is it possible to inject into the CMS a list of data pulled from Dynamics 365/CRM?

Comment: How often does this list of data get updated in CRM? Maybe a simple PowerShell script that pulls the data from CRM and uploads to your CMS would do the trick without any fancy direct live coupling.

Comment: Thanks @Filburt. Unfortunately the client wants the direct live coupling =)

Comment: If you need live access, look into the [Common Data Service API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/overview) the data retrieval itself is not to complicated but authentication can be challenging.

Comment: Thanks @Filburt, that avenue didn't even occur to me! We have an Azure account, maybe I could expose it using CDS and a Logic App. Thanks again!

Comment: If you have an Azure Subscription at your disposal and have more use cases coming where you'll have to consume more read-only CRM data, using the built-in Data Export to an Azure SQL instance might also be a very comfortable way.

Comment: Another great option. Thanks @Filburt